# Python Ray not starting properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, python3

I am starting ray on my ubuntu by using this command:

```
ray start --head --port=6379
```

All fine, ray runtime started. But when I check the `raylet.out` file in logs. It states something like this:

```
Export Agent to metrics failed: Can't connect to all addresses.
```

I installed ray using: `pip3 install 'ray[default]'` on Python 3.8.

[image]

Comment: what does the question have to do with [tag:cluster-ssh]?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.